# express.js different routes adding different assets

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have my javascripts in the normal public/js/ folder, everything works normally for normal routes like '/', '/blogs' etc

```
    app.get('/blog', routes.blog)
    app.get('/', routes.index)
```

so when loading assets to the client express logs

```
    GET /js/jquery.js 304 3ms
    GET /js/bootstrap.js 304 3ms
    GET /js/showdown.js 304 2ms
```

here everything is good, however when I try to add a parameter to a get request like so

```
    app.get('/blog/:title', routes.blog)
```

I get asset loading logs like this

```
    GET /blog/js/jquery.js 404 2ms
    GET /blog/js/bootstrap.js 404 2ms
    GET /blog/showdown.js 404 2ms
```

Why is it changing the directory to '/blog/' for the js.

I have not changed anything from the normal express app.js setup, so I will post it and all my dependencies if needed but first I would like to see is there a common solution to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your HTML is using relative URLs for the `src`

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Change that to an absolute URL starting with a `/` and you'll be fine.

Comment: @MichaelSmith you should accept my answer so others don't keep reading this question unnecessarily. Plus yummy rep points for me!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's because your HTML file loads the assets using relative paths, so once a second forward slash appears in the URL the paths get messed up. So for instance; *"/blog"* = good, *"/blog/"* = bad. You need to either use absolute paths for your assets (paths starting with a forward slash, e.g. *"/blog/js/jquery.js"*), or write the paths dynamically using a template system (something like
*"{{rootpath}}blog/js/jquery.js"*).